# Android Screen cut off - React Native

Tags: android, react-native

When I run my React Native App on Android (real device or Simulator) the screens are to big somehow and get cut off at the bottom (looks almost like as if the missing part is as high as the status bar, but I don't know if it has something to do with it, check the last screenshot)

The parent view is a simple View with `flex: 1` and the rest is relative to that.

Am I missing something on Android? It's my first Android App, I've only done iOS before.

I have the following code to test it:

```
return (
  <View
    style={{
      backgroundColor: 'red',
      width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
      height: Dimensions.get('window').height - 24, // 24 = status bar???
    }}
  >
    <Text>{Dimensions.get('window').height}</Text>
  </View>
);
```

I have figured out that it's exactly 24 to high - is this because of the status bar? If so, is it safe to use 24 or does it vary?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Provide a sample of your code which has this problem, so it's possible to test it.

Comment: @MeysamIzadmehr done - sorry